# XSLT 2.0 : Group and Copy Nodes based on a condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is my source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>567899</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>190.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>2000.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>    
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Expected Output**

Group the nodes based on unique `<Date>` value and copy all nodes that doesn't have `<Date>` element along with node that has unique `<Date>`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Records>
        <Worker> <!-- This node doesnt have <Date> element -->
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID> 
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker><!-- This node doesnt have <Date> element  -->
            <UniqueID>567899</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>190.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>2000.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>  <!--  <Date> value is unique 2023-10-06-07:00 -->
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID> 
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>  <!--  <Date> value is unique 2023-10-06-07:00 -->
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>        
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <Worker> <!-- This node needs to repeat as it does'nt have <Date> element -->
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID> 
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker> <!-- This node needs to repeat as it does'nt have <Date> element -->
            <UniqueID>567899</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>190.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>2000.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker> <!--  <Date> value is unique 2023-10-06-07:00 -->
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>   
        <Worker> <!--  <Date> value is unique 2023-10-06-07:00 -->
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>        
    </Records>
</Workers>
```

**First `<Records>` node** - `<Worker>` nodes with `<UniqueID>`values `67896` and `567899` are placed along with another `<Worker>` node that has `<UniqueID>` value 4567 and `<Date>` 2023-10-06-07:00

**My current XSLT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        
            <xsl:copy>
                <Records>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Worker[not(exists(Date))]"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker[exists(Date)]" group-by="Date">                       
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[exists(Date)]"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </Records>
            </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My current output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>567899</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>190.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>2000.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
         </Worker>
         <Worker>
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
         </Worker>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
         </Worker>
         <Worker>
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
         </Worker>
      </Worker>
   </Records>
</Workers>
```

**Issues**

Nodes with unique `<Date>` is not being copied along with `<Worker>` as in the expected output.

Could anyone take a look at and help me understand what I should be doing to get desired output.

Thanks

Comment: Why does your expected output have two `Records` elements (which seem identical)?

Comment: Also, can two `Worker` elements have the same `Date` but different `UniqueID`? If so, what should the result look like then?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k,  The elements `Records` are holding unique values of `<Date>` , first `Records' element has a date `2023-10-06-07:00` where as second `Records` element is holding a `Date` value 2023-10-10-07:00.

Comment: yes - as provided in the source XML, two `Worker` elements can have same `Date` for e.g. `UniqueID` with values 12354 and 4567 have same `Date`.

Comment: The first two `Worker` should be repeating from source XML example because those two `Worker` nodes do not contain `Date' field. So `Worker` nodes do not contain `Date' element needs to be copied along with `Worker' nodes that has a unique date. Since there are two unique date on the source, two `Records` elements need to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure I follow your logic correctly, though I believe this will return the expected result:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Workers">
    <Workers>
        <xsl:variable name="undated" select="Worker[not(Date)]" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker" group-by="Date">
            <Records>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$undated"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </Records>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Workers>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. The logic is - e.g - if there are 5 different date values in source XML, 5 `Records` nodes should be created and each `Record` node should contain `Worker` nodes that has same value of `Date` elements. Second condition is, `Worker` node that doesn't have `Date` element should be present in all 5 `Records`. so in my source xml, there are two different dates such as `2023-10-06-07:00` and `2023-10-10-07:00` so my result xml should have two `Records` nodes. Each Record node should have Worker node with a unique date along with `Worker` nodes that do not have `Date'

Comment: I believe that's exactly what my code does.

Comment: Hi  michael.hor257k - Sir, I had to create a new question because of an issue that I'm facing with current node because of structure of XML was slightly diferent from that I originally thought it would be. If you have time, could you take a look at this please? Thanks!
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424407/xslt-2-0-group-and-copy-nodes-based-on-condition-error