# XSLT 2.0 - Group and copy nodes based on condition - Error

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

**Here is my source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>        
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>        
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do.

- There are 4 different dates in the whole document, such as `2023-10-10-07:00` `2023-10-09-07:00` and `2023-10-06-07:00` `2023-10-08-07:00`
- Since my final output should be based on `<Date>` and 4 different
  dates are there on my source xml, my expected result should have 4
  `<Records>`nodes and each  node holding unique
  `<Date>`element corresponding to `<Worker>`
- However, there are 2 `<Worker>` nodes that do not have any `<Date>` elements so any `<Worker>` nodes do not have `<Date>` should be copied under all `<Records>` nodes

**My current XSLT**. Thanks to michael.hor257k

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Workers">
        <Workers>
            <xsl:variable name="undated" select="Worker[not(Misc)]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dated" select="Worker[(Misc)]"/>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker/Misc" group-by="Date">
                <Records>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$undated"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </Records>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Workers>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My current result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Misc>
         <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
         <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
      </Misc>
   </Records>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Misc>
         <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
         <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
      </Misc>
      <Misc>
         <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
         <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
      </Misc>
   </Records>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Misc>
         <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
         <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
      </Misc>
   </Records>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Misc>
         <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
         <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
      </Misc>
   </Records>
</Workers>
```

My current output has 4 `<Records>` nodes as expected but `<Misc>`--> `<Date>` doesn't have it's parent `<Worker>` node as below, which is incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Records>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Misc> <!-- Misc should have been under it's <Worker> node -->
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Records>
</Workers>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Records>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Worker>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>

            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Worker>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Worker>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Worker>
    </Records>
</Workers>
```

Can you help me figure out the issue please? Thank you!

**======================================================**
**Only below part is edited**
**Result after applying XSLT** michael.hor257k provided get the expected result based on the source XML originally provided. However, it is possible on my source XML to have more than one `<Misc>`node for a same `<Date>` but with different `<BonusAmount>` under `<Worker>` node, like below.

```
**Source Data**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>        
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount> <!-- Amount is 400 here -->
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount> <!-- Amount is 600 here -->
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

XSLT produces following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Records>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
         </Misc>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
         <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
         <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
         <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount>
         </Misc>
      </Worker>
   </Records>
</Workers>
```

**Expected Result is below**, both `<Misc>` elements should be grouped under same `<Worker>` node

Any help is appreciated in getting the result as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>678965</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Final Solution that gets the expected result is**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Workers">
        <Workers>
            <xsl:variable name="undated" select="Worker[not(Misc)]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker/Misc" group-by="Date">
                <Records>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$undated"/>
                    <Worker>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../(UniqueID | ExpenseAmount)"/>
                    </Worker>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Records>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Workers>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Workers">
    <Workers>
        <xsl:variable name="undated" select="Worker[not(Misc)]" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker/Misc" group-by="Date">
            <Records>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$undated"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <Worker>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../(UniqueID|ExpenseAmount)"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </Worker>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Workers>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much michael.hor257k, it gets somewhere close to what I was expecting. No fault with your code. That worked for the source XML I originally provided but my source XML can also have more than one `Misc' element for a same `Date` but with different `BonusAmount` . I edited original post with source XML, expected result and current result.

Comment: The result you show makes sense only if the Misc elements with the same Date have also the same UniqueID and ExpenseAmount. If that's always the case, then the necessary adjustment is minor and you should be able to make it yourself.

Comment: yes, Misc elements with same Date will always have same UniqueID and ExpenseAmount.

Comment: I got the result that I was expecting with a minor change but i took an hour to get what I wanted because of my overthinking, thank you so much michael.hor257k. Posted the solution for any one else who come here for a solution but one question i have is , `<xsl:copy-of select="../(UniqueID | ExpenseAmount)"/>` is the only way to copy all elements above `Misc` . I was trying a way by not specifically calling out elements so tried `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` to copy all elements above `Misc` but doesn't appear to be working. Any hint you can give me will be grateful?

Comment: You can use `<xsl:copy-of select="../(* except Misc)"/>`.